# Creating an object for a form in React / Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm wanting to create a form that will be used for both editing and creating a new object.

So if let's say I have,

```
interface IDog {
  name: string
  type: string
}

interface IDogForm {
  dog: IDog
}

const DogForm = (props: IDogForm) => {
  const { dog } = props
  const [value, setValue] = useState<IDog>(dog)

  return (
    <input value={dog?.name} />
    <input value={dog?.type} />
  )
}
```

Since I'm using the same form for editing and creating a new object, sometimes `dog` can be undefined. In which case, I've added `dog?.name` as a check to see if `dog` exists. My main question is, would it be a good idea to do something like this in addition to checking for existence:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<IDog>({
  name: '', 
  type: '' 
})
```

Or in the parent component, I could do something like this:

```
const dog = {} as IModal
```

Although, from what I've read it's not the greatest idea to do it that way because I'll lose type safety.

Comment: Why instead of adding the `?` in the value you add it in the `IDog interface` after name and type?

Comment: Because they are required fields that need to be completed in the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make `dog` optional in `IDogForm`:

```
interface IDogForm {
  dog?: IDog
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
const newDog: IDog = { name: '', type: '' }

const DogForm = ({ dog }: IDogForm) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(dog ?? newDog)

  return <>
    <input value={value.name} />
    <input value={value.type} />
  </>
}
```

Now `dog` is optional, but if its present then all fields on that dog are required. By initializing the state with `dog ?? newDog` you provide a blank dog to use when one is not passed in.

Now you can use this component with our without a `dog`.

```
const testA = <DogForm dog={{ name: 'Fido', type: 'good boy' }} />
const testB = <DogForm />
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAORSoYsBQXwAdpSh10VAJIARCAHNcXOHD4oQSAFxxCMKPyly4MAJ5hV6zdq7Ue-QcLRjJUgGLRmOXQBNpAfjUTp5nmgQfBoKSADu9j72cAC8uApKxiws2AZGask0AUEh9k5QzHEAFHgeMtRR0vkgAJSxAHyy8oHB8ADaAG4oADb4SNjEMABqPX0AurEExGQUSEVlcJ6eoRHSNTzy7DD4UHxwADz1uvL7-GD48F29SDE4V30AdIrKtAD0R-InZxdw9zd3oyQDzSSDeHwO738XBaIUoGgAgpN9nlnHAyrc8M8kg5gB4UnpDEkpBAIG44AAjCD6Fg0MHQnLwOEwABCSJRBTg7yAA)